# how to know why the kube-proxy stopped

Tags: kubernetes

Today I found the kubernetes v1.15.2 cluster one node's kube-proxy process was stopped, this is the stopped status:

```
[root@uat-k8s-01 ~]# systemctl status -l kube-proxy
● kube-proxy.service - Kubernetes Kube-Proxy Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kube-proxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2020-04-18 08:04:18 CST; 2 weeks 0 days ago
     Docs: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
  Process: 937394 ExecStart=/opt/k8s/bin/kube-proxy --config=/etc/kubernetes/kube-proxy-config.yaml --logtostderr=true --v=2 (code=killed, signal=PIPE)
 Main PID: 937394 (code=killed, signal=PIPE)

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

from this log tips I did not know why the kube-proxy process stopped. This is the kube-proxy service config:

```
[root@uat-k8s-01 ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/kube-proxy.service
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes Kube-Proxy Server
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/k8s/k8s/kube-proxy
ExecStart=/opt/k8s/bin/kube-proxy \
  --config=/etc/kubernetes/kube-proxy-config.yaml \
  --logtostderr=true \
  --v=2
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

is there any way to find out why the kube-proxy failed and avoid stop the next time? This is the journal log output:

```
[root@uat-k8s-01 ~]# journalctl -u kube-proxy.service
-- No entries --
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post logs for `kube-proxy`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/#looking-at-logs ?

Comment: Do you see kube-proxy pod in kube-system namespace?

Comment: there is no log named `kube-proxy.log` in folder `/var/log/`  Grigoriy Mikhalkin

Comment: no, I am install kube proxy by handle in host machine, not running in kuberetes cluster.@ArghyaSadhu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `journalctl -u kube-proxy.service` or check `/var/log/kube-proxy.log` to see kube-proxy logs. In a real production setup you should send logs to a log aggregator system such as ELK or splunk so that logs are not lost.